# Convert webm to jpg or png

Tags: video, desktop-background, convert

I found many .webm videos on the net and I want to know if it's possible to extract images from these.

Some videos I found have amazing images and I would like to set one of the frames as wallpaper.

I am using 12.04, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code works for me:

```
avconv -ss 30 -i my-cool-movie.webm -frames 1 -f image2 my-cool-picture.png
```

In this command,

`-ss 30` specifies that you want to take the frame 30 seconds into the movie

`-i my-cool-movie.webm` specifies the name of the movie from which to take the frame

`-frames 1` stops the program from extracting more than one frame

`-f image2 my-cool-picture.png` sets the output format to image and filename to my-cool-picture.png.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to make it that complicated, you can simple use [webm to png](https://www.converter365.com/video-converter/webm/webm-to-png) online converter. I am using it for some time now, even for my business projects.

Comment: One terminal command is hardly 'complicated'.

Comment: True. I just shared my way of doing it. It might help someone. :)